# Check if records exists in a Postgres table

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, csv, postgresql-copy

I have to read a CSV every 20 seconds. Each CSV contains min. of 500 to max. 60000 lines. I have to insert the data in a Postgres table, but before that I need to check if the items have already been inserted, because there is a high probability of getting duplicate item. The field to check for uniqueness is also indexed.

So, I read the file in chunks and use the IN clause to get the items already in the database.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Add proper unique indexes and just perform the inserts, ignoring duplicate errors.

Comment: will that have better performance in large sets of data?

Comment: @meagar: You can't just "ignore duplicate errors" with set-based operations. The transaction will be rolled back and nothing gets done. Would only make sense if you `INSERT` rows one by one - which would be a terrible idea, as far as performance is concerned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should perform well:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 0 -- copy layout, but no data

COPY tmp FROM '/absolute/path/to/file' FORMAT csv;

INSERT INTO tbl
SELECT tmp.*
FROM   tmp
LEFT   JOIN tbl USING (tbl_id)
WHERE  tbl.tbl_id IS NULL;

DROP TABLE tmp; -- else dropped at end of session automatically
```

Closely related to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8910810/939860).

Comment: @TheRaaaZ: Join on enough columns to *make* it unique. *All columns* if you have to. The [`USING` or the `NATURAL` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) would come in handy for that. Normally, every table should have a primary key, though.

Comment: @ervin I've columns array, can you please tell what will be the query if columns array have 5 columns col1-col5?

Comment: @TheRaaaZ: [Start a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), giving a complete picture. You can always link to this one for reference.

Answer (score 1):

First just for completeness I changed Erwin's code to use `except`

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp AS SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 0 -- copy layout, but no data
COPY tmp FROM '/absolute/path/to/file' FORMAT csv;

INSERT INTO tbl
SELECT tmp.*
FROM   tmp
except
select *
from tbl

DROP TABLE tmp;
```

Then I resolved to test it myself. I tested it in 9.1 with a mostly untouched `postgresql.conf`. The target table contains 10 million rows and the origin table 30 thousand. 15 thousand already exists in the target table.

```
create table tbl (id integer primary key)
;
insert into tbl
select generate_series(1, 10000000)
;
create temp table tmp as select * from tbl limit 0
;
insert into tmp
select generate_series(9985000, 10015000)
;
```

I asked for the explain of the select part only. The `except` version:

```
explain
select *
from tmp
except
select *
from tbl
;
                                       QUERY PLAN                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashSetOp Except  (cost=0.00..270098.68 rows=200 width=4)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..245018.94 rows=10031897 width=4)
         ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.00..771.40 rows=31920 width=4)
               ->  Seq Scan on tmp  (cost=0.00..452.20 rows=31920 width=4)
         ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..244247.54 rows=9999977 width=4)
               ->  Seq Scan on tbl  (cost=0.00..144247.77 rows=9999977 width=4)
(6 rows)
```

The `outer join` version:

```
explain
select *
from 
    tmp
    left join
    tbl using (id)
where tbl.id is null
;
                                QUERY PLAN                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.00..208142.58 rows=15960 width=4)
   ->  Seq Scan on tmp  (cost=0.00..452.20 rows=31920 width=4)
   ->  Index Scan using tbl_pkey on tbl  (cost=0.00..7.80 rows=1 width=4)
         Index Cond: (tmp.id = id)
(4 rows)
```