# Check if exist else insert in sql from csv without unique column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

Question is almost similar to [Check if records exists in a Postgres table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12756413/check-if-records-exists-in-a-postgres-table) but in my case, i don't have any unique column. Currently i'm adding records from csv to mysql using php with this query:

```
"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file."' INTO TABLE $table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '$fieldSeperator' ";
```

where `$file` is csv file, `$table` is name of table and `$fieldSeperator` is `,` or `\t`

But the above query can only add new record without comapring to previous.
How to check for rows if they dont exist then add new else no change?

Comment: you will have to open the file and loop to process it, you wont be able to use LOAD DATA if you need row by row processing

Comment: @Dagon is there any solution like http://stackoverflow.com/a/12756520/2037323 ?

Comment: from what i understand of your question, no.

Comment: I asked @erwin-brandstetter about that but was not able to understand that, he replied: Join on enough columns to make it unique. All columns if you have to. The USING or the NATURAL clause would come in handy for that. Normally, every table should have a primary key, though

Comment: or may be to create a temp table and then compare both tables and then add?

Comment: how do you determine, what should be added ?

Comment: let first records added from csv and after that, i change/add a record in csv, now when i load that csv, it should only add 1 new record to that table