# How can I insert common data into a temp table from disparate schemas?

Tags: java, postgresql

I am not sure how to solve this problem:

We import order information from a variety of online vendors ( Amazon, Newegg etc ). Each vendor has their own specific terminology and structure for their orders that we have mirrored into a database. Our data imports into the database with no issues, however the problem I am faced with is to write a method that will extract required fields from the database, regardless of the schema.

For instance assume we have the following structures:

**Newegg structure:**

```
"OrderNumber" integer NOT NULL, -- The Order Number
"InvoiceNumber" integer, -- The invoice number
"OrderDate" timestamp without time zone, -- Create date.
```

**Amazon structure:**

```
"amazonOrderId" character varying(25) NOT NULL, -- Amazon's unique, displayable identifier for an order.
"merchant-order-id" integer DEFAULT 0, -- A unique identifier optionally supplied for the order by the Merchant.
"purchase-date" timestamp with time zone, -- The date the order was placed.
```

**How can I select these items and place them into a temporary table for me to query against?**

The temporary table could look like:

```
"OrderNumber" character varying(25) NOT NULL,
"TransactionId" integer,
"PurchaseDate" timestamp with time zone
```

I understand that some of the databases represent an order number with an integer and others a character varying; to handle that I plan on casting the datatypes to String values.

Does anyone have a suggestion for me to read about that will help me figure this out?

**I don't need an exact answer, just a nudge in the right direction.**

The data will be consumed by Java, so if any particular Java classes will help, feel free to suggest them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you can create a [`VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html) to provide this functionality:

```sql
CREATE VIEW orders AS
SELECT '1'::int            AS source -- or any other tag to identify source
      ,"OrderNumber"::text AS order_nr
      ,"InvoiceNumber"     AS tansaction_id -- no cast .. is int already
      ,"OrderDate" AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS purchase_date -- !! see explanation
FROM   tbl_newegg

UNION  ALL  -- not UNION!
SELECT 2
       "amazonOrderId"
      ,"merchant-order-id"
      ,"purchase-date"
FROM   tbl_amazon;
```

You can query this view like any other table:

```sql
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_nr = 123 AND source = 2;
```

- The `source` is necessary if the `order_nr` is not unique. How else would you guarantee unique order-numbers over different sources?
- A `timestamp without time zone` is an ambiguous in a global context. It's only good in connection with its time zone. If you mix `timestamp` and `timestamptz`, you need to place the `timestamp` at a certain time zone with the `AT TIME ZONE` construct to make this work. For more explanation read [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170).

  I use UTC as time zone, you might want to provide a different one. A simple cast `"OrderDate"::timestamptz` would assume your current time zone. `AT TIME ZONE` applied to a `timestamp` results in `timestamptz`. That's why I did not add another cast.
- While you *can*, I advise not to use camel-case identifiers in PostgreSQL *ever*. Avoids many kinds of possible confusion. Note the lower case identifiers (without the now unnecessary double-quotes) I supplied.
- Don't use `varchar(25)` as type for the `order_nr`. Just use `text` without arbitrary length modifier if it has to be a string. If all order numbers consist of digits exclusively, `integer` or `bigint` would be faster.

#### Performance

One way to make this fast would be to materialize the view. I.e., write the result into a (temporary) table:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_orders AS
SELECT * FROM orders;

ANALYZE tmp_orders; -- temp tables are not auto-analyzed!

ALTER TABLE tmp_orders
ADD constraint orders_pk PRIMARY KEY (order_nr, source);
```

You *need* an index. In my example, the primary key constraint provides the index automatically.

If your tables are big, make sure you have enough *temporary buffers* to handle this in RAM *before* you create the temp table. Else it will actually slow you down.

```sql
SET temp_buffers = 1000MB;
```

Has to be the first call to temp objects in your session. Don't set it high globally, just for your session. A temp table is dropped automatically at the end of your session anyway.

To get an estimate how much RAM you need, create the table once and measure:

```sql
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('tmp_orders'));
```

More on object sizes under this [related question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/23879/3684).

All the overhead only pays if you have to process a number of queries within one session. For other use cases there are other solutions. If you know the source table at the time of the query, it would be much faster to direct your query to the source table instead. If you don't, I would question the uniqueness of your `order_nr` once more. If it is, in fact, guaranteed to be unique you can drop the column `source` I introduced.

For only one or a few queries, it might be faster to use the view instead of the materialized view.

I would also consider a **plpgsql function** that queries one table after the other until the record is found. Might be cheaper for a couple of queries, considering the overhead. Indexes for every table needed of course.

Also, if you stick to `text` or `varchar` for your `order_nr`, consider [`COLLATE "C"`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-COLLATE-EXPRS) for it.

Comment: Wow - Thanks for taking the time to write this out - I appreciate it immensely. I will for sure be reading this answer several times to make sure I digest it all. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to create an abstract class that will define the basics of interacting with the data, then derive a class per database schema you need to access. This will allow the core code to operate on a single object type, and each implementation can then specify the queries in a form specific to that database schema.

Something like:

```
public class Order
{
    private String orderNumber;
    private BigDecimal orderTotal;
    ... etc ...
}

public abstract class AbstractOrderInformation
{
  public abstract ArrayList<Order> getOrders();
  ...
}
```

with a Newegg class:

```
public class NeweggOrderInformation extends AbstractOrderInformation
{
   public ArrayList<Order> getOrders() {
      ... do the work of getting the newegg order
   }
 ...
}
```

Then you can have an arbitrarily large number of formats and when you need information, you can just iterate over all the implementations and get the Orders from each.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid specific classes for each marketplace as we have 13 and counting, so that is 13 classes, plus an additional class being required for each new marketplace, however its better then the current implementation :)