# Switching from FOR loops in plpgsql to set-based SQL commands

Tags: postgresql, xml-parsing, case, plpgsql, query-performance

I've got quite heavy query with `FOR` loop to rewrite and would like to do it simpler, using more SQL instead of plpgsql constructions. The query looks like:

```
FOR big_xml IN SELECT unnest(xpath('//TAG1', my_xml)) LOOP
   str_xml = unnest(xpath('/TAG2/TYPE/text()', big_xml));

      FOR single_xml IN SELECT unnest(xpath('/TAG2/single', big_xml)) LOOP

         CASE str_xml::INT
           WHEN 1
           THEN
            INSERT INTO tab1(id, xml) VALUES (1, single_xml);
           WHEN 2
           THEN
            INSERT INTO tab2(id, xml) VALUES (1, single_xml);
           WHEN 3
            [...] 
           WHEN 11
            [...]
           ELSE 
              RAISE EXCEPTION 'something'
           END CASE;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

RETURN xmlelement(NAME "out", xmlforest(1 AS out));
```

I've started to rewrite it for better performance with:

```
INSERT INTO tab1(id, xml)
  SELECT 1, unnest(xpath('/TAG2/single', (SELECT unnest(xpath('//TAG1', my_xml))));
```

But I'm not sure how to deal with those `CASE ... INSERT` statements.
Any ideas?
Or maybe my approach is completely wrong?

edited 25.02.14: PostgreSQL 9.3.1

Comment: As always, sample values and your Postgres version would be helpful.

Comment: `unnest()` in this statement in your original doesn't make sense: `str_xml = unnest(xpath('/TAG2/TYPE/text()', big_xml))`. If returns multiple rows, the code breaks; if that cannot happen, `unnest()` doesn't make sense ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert into different tables, depending on your data, you need some procedural code. But you can make do with a single loop and a nested `unnest()`:

```
DEFINE
   int_xml    int;
   single_xml xml;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN                     -- or you can use two variables
      SELECT xpath('/TAG2/single', big_xml))[1]::text::int AS int_xml
           , unnest(xpath('/TAG2/TYPE/text()', big_xml)) AS single_xml
      FROM  (SELECT unnest(xpath('//TAG1', my_xml)) AS big_xml) sub
   LOOP
      CASE int_xml
      WHEN 1 THEN
         INSERT INTO tab1(id, xml) VALUES (1, single_xml);
      WHEN 2 THEN
         INSERT INTO tab2(id, xml) VALUES (1, single_xml);
      WHEN 3 THEN
          ...

      ELSE 
         RAISE EXCEPTION 'something'
      END CASE;
   END LOOP;
END
```

Or take a temporary table or CTE and append multiple `INSERT` statements. Should be faster for lots of rows.

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT xpath('/TAG2/single', big_xml))[1]::text::int AS int_xml
        , unnest(xpath('/TAG2/TYPE/text()', big_xml)) AS single_xml
   FROM  (SELECT unnest(xpath('//TAG1', my_xml)) AS big_xml) sub
), i1 AS (
   INSERT INTO tab1(id, xml)
   SELECT 1, single_xml
   FROM   cte
   WHERE  int_xml = 1
), i2 AS (
   INSERT INTO tab2(id, xml)
   SELECT 1, single_xml
   FROM   cte
   WHERE  int_xml = 2
),
   ...
)
SELECT int_xml INTO my_var
FROM   cte
WHERE  int_xml <> ALL ({'1','2','3','11'}::int[])
LIMIT  1;

IF FOUND THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'One of the int_xml did not fit: %!', my_var;
END IF;
```

The last bit compensates for the exception in your original.

If your `big_xml` is real big, make sure you provide enough temporary buffers for the CTE. If the general setting is too low, increase the `temp_buffers` setting for this session only. Details in this related answer:
[How can I insert common data into a temp table from disparate schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316181/how-can-i-insert-common-data-into-a-temp-table-from-disparate-schemas/13317965#13317965)

Comment: thank you for your answer, it's excellent as always, but I wasn't specific enough about INSERT statement. When value equals 1 then insert goes to tab1, when 2 to tab2 etc. So should I use dynamic SQL for that? Or there is a way to write it with standard SQL?

Comment: so I need some mapping between TYPE in xml and table name. Maybe through unlogged table and join?

Comment: @Borys; I rewrote the answer to accommodate different target tables. Consider the update.