# SELECT multiple rows and columns into a record variable

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

In a plpgsql function, how can multiple rows and columns be selected into a record variable?

For example, I would like to `SELECT` multiple instances of two columns (`yearinteger` and `value`) into a record variable (`yearvalues`).

*EDIT - the following code is just part of a longer function, I need the variable `yearvalues` to contain multiple rows and columns from a table from which I can create further variables from

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_function ()
RETURNS TABLE () AS $$
DECLARE
    year c.year%TYPE;
    value c.value%TYPE;
    yearvalues record;
BEGIN
    FOR yearvalues IN 
    SELECT c.year, c.value FROM c
    LOOP
    END LOOP;
-- creation of additional variables from the yearvalues variable
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: ... and when you run this function, what happens? (Always show exact error message text).

Comment: read [this](http://www.day32.com/MySQL/Meetup/Presentations/postgresql_stored_procedures.pdf) and go through [PosgreSQL Resources in SO](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info)

Comment: If the function returns a table, why not use a `sql` function that simply returns the result of the `select`? Or a `return query` in the PL/pgSQL function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are no table variables in PL/pgSQL - at least up to Postgres 14, and likely never.

Use **temporary tables**:

- [Select from a table variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873735/select-from-a-table-variable/17873935#17873935)

Or substitute with **CTEs** (or just subqueries in simple cases) for the local scope of a single query. A "single query" can encompass multiple commands when using (data-modifying) CTEs. That would be most efficient:

- [Switching from FOR loops in plpgsql to set-based SQL commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978046/switching-from-for-loops-in-plpgsql-to-set-based-sql-commands/21999333#21999333)

Or combine **cursors** with loops (consider the example under *FNC - Function*):

- [Window Functions or Common Table Expressions: count previous rows within range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173412/window-functions-or-common-table-expressions-generate-a-count-of-previous-recor/18174102#18174102)

But it's typically simpler and more efficient to use the **implicit cursor** of a `FOR` loop:

- [Postgres FOR LOOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145761/postgres-for-loop/19147320#19147320)
- [Cursor based records in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22339628/cursor-based-records-in-postgresql/22340544#22340544)

Comment: thank you for describing the various options; I think cursors are what I am looking for.

Comment: what do you mean "(at least up to v9.4)" ? It's a bit confusing statement. Does that mean there are table variables in newer versions ?

Comment: @user544262772: How would I know that at the time of writing? There are still no table variables in version 10, and I don't expect that to change in future versions.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I have a question, please can you enter this room ?  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154260/a-question-about-postgresql-temporary-tables *this message will be deleted*