# Bulk upsert (insert-update) a csv in postgres

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, csv

I'm looking for a good way to bulk "upsert" a csv. The table is:

```
category_id (indexed but not unique)      post_id (indexed and unique)
```

a `post_id` should only be represented once.

Is there a good way to do this?

To do a bulk insert I've used the `COPY posts FROM 'posts.csv' CSV;` in psql, but I've never done a bulk "where exists update, else insert" type of operation.

Comment: Given that the data is in a csv, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Start with a temporary staging table and proceed from there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres/8910810#8910810

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter fair enough - thanks!