# Load data from CSV-file into PostgreSQL database

Tags: database, postgresql, csv

I have an application, that needs to load data from user-specified CSV-files into PostgreSQL database tables.

The structure of CSV-file is simple:

```
name,email
John Doe,john@example.com
...
```

In the database I have three tables:

```pgsql
---------------
-- CAMPAIGNS --
---------------

CREATE TABLE "campaigns" (
    "id"         serial  PRIMARY KEY,
    "name"       citext  UNIQUE CHECK ("name" ~ '^[-a-z0-9_]+$'),
    "title"      text
);

----------------
-- RECIPIENTS --
----------------

CREATE TABLE "recipients" (
    "id"           serial  PRIMARY KEY,
    "email"        citext  UNIQUE CHECK (length("email") <= 254),
    "name"         text
);


-----------------
-- SUBMISSIONS --
-----------------

CREATE TYPE "enum_submissions_status" AS ENUM (
    'WAITING',
    'SENT',
    'FAILED'
);

CREATE TABLE "submissions" (
    "id"           serial                     PRIMARY KEY,
    "campaignId"   integer                    REFERENCES "campaigns"   ON UPDATE CASCADE  ON DELETE CASCADE  NOT NULL,
    "recipientId"  integer                    REFERENCES "recipients"  ON UPDATE CASCADE  ON DELETE CASCADE  NOT NULL,
    "status"       "enum_submissions_status"  DEFAULT 'WAITING',
    "sentAt"       timestamp with time zone
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "submissions_unique" ON "submissions" ("campaignId", "recipientId");
CREATE INDEX "submissions_recipient_id_index" ON "submissions" ("recipientId");
```

I want to read all rows from the specified CSV-file and to make sure that according records exist in `recipients` and `submissions` tables.

What would be the most performance-efficient method to load data in these tables?

This is primarily a conceptual question, I'm not asking for a concrete implementation.

---

- First of all, I've naively tried to read and parse CSV-file line-by-line and issue `SELECT/INSERT` queries for each E-Mail. Obviously, it was a very slow solution that allowed me to load ~4k records per minute, but code was pretty simple and straightforward.
- Now, I'm reading the CSV-file line-by-line, but aggregating all E-Mails into a batches of 1'000 elements. All `SELECT/INSERT` queries are made in batches using `SELECT id, email WHERE email IN ('...', '...', '...', ...)` constructs. Such approach increased the performance, and now I have performance of ~25k records per minute. However, this approach demanded a pretty-complex multi-step code to work.

Are there any better approaches to solve this problem and get even greater performance?

---

The key problem here is that I need to insert data to the `recipients` table first and then I need to use the generated `id` to create a corresponding record in the `submissions` table.

Also, I need to make sure that inserted E-Mails are unique. Right now, I'm using a simple array-based index in my application to prevent duplicate E-Mails from being added to the batch.

I'm writing my app using `Node.js` and `Sequelize` with `Knex`, however, the concrete technology doesn't matter here much.

Comment: Load data into temporary table, then use any feature of SQL/PostgreSQL you needed.

Comment: Are you familiar with the COPY (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-copy.html)  command?  Bring it in to a temporary table and then use your inserts to populate the destination tables. (COPY isn't standard SQL btw)

Comment: Using `COPY` is the fastest way to go. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271377/postgres-csv-copy-from-import-is-not-respecting-csv-headers

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin has GUI for data import since 1.16. You have to create your table first and then you can import data easily - just right-click on the table name and click on Import.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NQux.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ienem.png)

Comment: I can't use some third-party graphical tool for this. I need to do this through my own application or at least via some kind of API.