# PSQL - UPDATE tableA off tableB where Column1 Match

Tags: postgresql

I have a broken column with null values, however I have managed to import the data off a csv into TempTable

MediaRecords - localpath column is null

TempTable - localpath column is correct

UPDATE mediarecords
SET localpath = TempTable.localpath
FROM TempTable
WHERE recordid = TempTable.recordid;

I keep getting ERROR:  relation "temptable" does not exist
LINE 3: FROM TempTable
however I can browse the table and see the data.
I tried following this [How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres) and here we are

Comment: Can you do a select * from temptable . Also, post some sample create table syntax for both tables or screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Hu Bucky, can you check how the table is actually called because I see you referring at it as `TempTable` with camelcase and the error states `temptable` all lowercase.

PostgreSQL could be case sensitive. As example if you do the following

```
create table "TempTableABC" (id int);
```

Trying to select from `temptableABC` will fail

```
defaultdb=> select * from temptableABC;
ERROR:  relation "temptableabc" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from temptableABC;
                      ^
```

You'll need to use the same quoted syntax to make it work

```
defaultdb=> select * from "TempTableABC";
 id 
----
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Hey, so  
  
SELECT * FROM public."TempTable";  
  
works however  
  
UPDATE mediarecords  
SET localpath = TempTable.localpath  
FROM public."TempTable"  
WHERE recordid = TempTable.recordid;  

does not

Comment: OK Cool, you set me on the correct path

UPDATE mediarecords 
SET localpath = "TempTable".localpath
FROM public."TempTable"
WHERE "mediarecords".recordid = "TempTable".recordid;

Works

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE mediarecords
SET localpath = "TempTable".localpath
FROM public."TempTable"
WHERE "mediarecords".recordid = "TempTable".recordid;

Worked