# PostgreSQL copy command gives error for temporary table

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I am trying to run the below command on the unix console :

```
env 'PGOPTIONS=-c search_path=admin -c client_min_messages=error' psql -h hostname -U user -p 1111 -d platform -c "CREATE TEMP TABLE admin.tmp_213 AS SELECT * FROM admin.file_status limit 0;\copy admin.tmp_213(feed_id,run_id,extracted_date,file_name,start_time,file_size,status,crypt_flag)  FROM '/opt/temp/213/list.up' delimiter ',' csv;UPDATE admin.file_status SET file_size = admin.tmp_213.file_size FROM  admin.tmp_213 A WHERE  admin.file_status.feed_id = A.feed_id and admin.file_status.file_name = A.file_name;"
```

I am getting the below error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: ...* FROM admin.file_status limit 0;\copy admi...
```

If I use the above command without a backslash before `COPY`, it gives me the below error:

```
ERROR:  cannot create temporary relation in non-temporary schema
```

I am doing the above to implement the solution as mentioned here:
[How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first error is because metacommands like \copy cannot be combined in the same line as regular commands when given with -c.  You can give two -c options, with one command in each instead.

The second error is self-explanatory.  You don't get to decide what schema your temp table goes to.  Just omit the schema.