# How to ignore errors with psql \copy meta-command

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am using `psql` with a PostgreSQL database and the following `copy` command:

```
\COPY isa (np1, np2, sentence) FROM 'c:\Downloads\isa.txt' WITH DELIMITER '|'
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
```

How can I skip the lines with errors?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot skip the errors without skipping the whole command up to and including Postgres 14. There is currently no more sophisticated error handling.

[`\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) is just a wrapper around SQL [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) that channels results through psql. The manual for `COPY`:

> **`COPY` stops operation at the first error.** This should not lead to problems in the event of a `COPY TO`, but the target table will
> already have received earlier rows in a `COPY FROM`. These rows will
> not be visible or accessible, but they still occupy disk space. This
> might amount to a considerable amount of wasted disk space if the
> failure happened well into a large copy operation. You might wish to
> invoke `VACUUM` to recover the wasted space.

Bold emphasis mine. And:

> `COPY FROM` will raise an error if any line of the input file contains
> more or fewer columns than are expected.

`COPY` is an extremely fast way to import / export data. Sophisticated checks and error handling would slow it down.

There was an [attempt to add error logging to `COPY` in Postgres 9.0](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Error_logging_in_COPY) but it was never committed.

#### Solution

Fix your input file instead.

If you have one or more additional columns in your input file and the file is **otherwise consistent**, you might add dummy columns to your table `isa` and drop those afterwards. Or (cleaner with production tables) import to a temporary staging table and `INSERT` selected columns (or expressions) to your target table `isa` from there.

Related answers with detailed instructions:

- [How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres/8910810#8910810)
- [COPY command: copy only specific columns from csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15707519/copy-command-copy-only-specific-columns-from-csv/15708171#15708171)

Comment: If I add additional table columns can I use something similar to my original command (with the additional columns) or do I need additional options for the optional columns?

Comment: I get: ERROR:  missing data for column "dummy1"

Comment: @Superdooperhero: Those would be columns just like other columns as far as `COPY` is concerned. Your "missing data" error indicates your input file is inconsistent - or you are not using the correct separator or escape characters. Either way, I would rather go with the 2nd option I mentioned: the temporary staging table. But you need a consistent file for that as well.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this answer years later: if you only have a few malformed lines in your input data, you can run the `\copy` command and postgres will report the line number the error is at. You can then remove this line with `sed -i '5d' input.tsv` (where 5 is the line number) and try running `\copy` again.

Comment: For anyone who read Balazs solution, it won't work. The Error report of which line is malformed isn't going to co-ordinate with the same line as in the input file. You will have to grep search to find what that line will be and remove it with sed. ie. It reported Error line 283678, but grepped and found it to be 126092 in the file.

Answer (score 6):

It is too bad that in 25 years Postgres doesn't have `-ignore-errors` flag or option for `COPY` command. In this era of BigData you get a lot of dirty records and it can be very costly for the project to fix every outlier.

I had to make a work-around this way:

1. Copy the original table and call it `dummy_original_table`
2. in the original table, create a trigger like this:

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION on_insert_in_original_table() RETURNS trigger AS  $$  
    DECLARE
        v_rec   RECORD;
    BEGIN
        -- we use the trigger to prevent 'duplicate index' error by returning NULL on duplicates
        SELECT * FROM original_table WHERE primary_key=NEW.primary_key INTO v_rec;
        IF v_rec IS NOT NULL THEN
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF; 
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO original_table(datum,primary_key) VALUES(NEW.datum,NEW.primary_key)
                ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                NULL;
        END;
        RETURN NULL;
    END;
```

3. Run a copy into the dummy table. No record will be inserted there, but all of them will be inserted in the original_table

`psql dbname -c \copy dummy_original_table(datum,primary_key) FROM '/home/user/data.csv' delimiter E'\t'`

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution -- import the batch file one line at a time.  The performance can be much slower, but it may be sufficient for your scenario:

```
#!/bin/bash

input_file=./my_input.csv
tmp_file=/tmp/one-line.csv
cat $input_file | while read input_line; do
    echo "$input_line" > $tmp_file
    psql my_database \
     -c "\
     COPY my_table \
     FROM `$tmp_file` \
     DELIMITER '|'\
     CSV;\
    "
done
```

Additionally, you could modify the script to capture the `psql` stdout/stderr and exit
status, and if the exit status is non-zero, echo `$input_line` and the captured stdout/stderr to stdin and/or append it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: remove the reported errant line using `sed` and run `\copy` again

Later versions of Postgres (including Postgres 13), will report the line number of the error.  You can then remove that line with `sed` and run \copy again, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/bash
bad_line_number=5  # assuming line 5 is the bad line
sed ${bad_line_number}d < input.csv > filtered.csv
```

[per [the comment from @Botond_Balázs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634360/how-to-ignore-errors-with-psql-copy-meta-command/65676394#comment113076520_36635312) ]

Comment: This can't work /copy bad line numbers do not match up with the line numbers in the files. Something to do when when the error reports.  I have confirmed this with live data. 'Error: line 283678' is actually line 126092 'Error: line 855531'   is actually line 642693. So not a good solution.