# How to import from a mixed-encoding file to a PostgreSQL table

Tags: sql, postgresql, encoding, utf-8, windows-1255

I have a 30 GB text file. the encoding of the file is UTF8 but it also contains some Windows-1252 characters. So, when I try to import, it gives the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x9b
```

How can I fix this?

the file already has UTF8 format, when i run the 'file' command for this file it says the encoding is UTF8. but it also contains some not UTF8 byte sequences. for example when I run the \copy command after a while it gives the above mentioned error for this row:

```
0B012234    Basic study of <img src="/fulltext-image.asp?format=htmlnonpaginated&src=323K744431152658_html\233_2    basic study of img src fulltext image asp format htmlnonpaginated src 323k744431152658_html 233_2   1975        Semigroup Forum semigroup forum 04861B53        19555
```

Comment: Use `iconv` on Linux/Unix or cygwin (windows). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867272/invalid-byte-sequence-for-encoding-utf8/4867690#4867690

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz the file already has UTF8 format, when i run the 'file' command for this file it says the encoding is UTF8. but it also contains some not UTF8  byte sequences. how inconv command can help?

Comment: Can you put a sample with the mixed encoding?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the backslash (`\`).
Use CSV format which does not treat backslash as a special character, e.g. -

```
\copy t from myfile.txt with csv quote E'\x1' delimiter E'\x2'
```