# Issue with importing formatted numbers over 1,000 with COPY

Tags: postgresql, csv, bulkinsert, sqldatatypes, postgresql-copy

I have a Postgres database and have been trying to import a CSV file into a table with the code below. I keep getting the error

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: " 1,183.26 "
> ```

I assume the issue is that there is a `,` in the value but when I go into the CSV and try to edit the value it seems like the `,` is added automatically by Excel.

```
COPY invtest5
FROM 'C:\Users\Hank\Downloads\SampleData\SampleDataCSV.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' 
CSV HEADER;
```

The table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE invtest5 (
    OrderDate date,
    Region varchar(255),
    Rep varchar(255),
    Item varchar(255),
    Units int,
    Unit_Cost numeric(15,3),
    Total numeric(15,3)
);
```

I am looking for a way to import the data whether or not the number has a `,` in it.

Comment: If you open the file with a text editor not Excel do you see the commas in the numbers or is Excel 'helpfully' adding that for you? And if it does have the , is the value enclosed in quotes?

Comment: @Reeza It still shows the comma in a text editor, in quotes, but when I click on the cell in Excel it doesn't show it as being there when I input the value. So I think Excel is adding them but also not letting me delete them. For example if I click on the cell of the `1,183.26` it shows up as `1183.26` when I edit it but afterwards it goes back to having a comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

' 1,183.26 ' is not a valid [numeric literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#id-1.5.3.5.9.9.2). [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) is fast and simple, but not fault-tolerant. Requires valid input.

Some options to fix:

1. Format numbers in Excel without "group separator" (that's what the noise `,` is).
2. Edit the CSV to remove group separators. (But don't remove other commas!)
3. If you can afford to [`ALTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) the column type in the target table (i.e. **no** concurrent load on the DB, you have the necessary privileges, and no depending objects that would block), you could:

```sql
ALTER TABLE invtest5
  ALTER unit_cost TYPE text
, ALTER total     TYPE text;     -- both columns?

COPY ...

ALTER TABLE invtest5
  ALTER unit_cost TYPE numeric(15,3) USING (replace(unit_cost, ',', '')::numeric)
, ALTER total     TYPE numeric(15,3) USING (replace(total    , ',', '')::numeric);
```

The expression `(replace(unit_cost, ',', '')::numeric)` removes all commas before casting to `numeric`.

Leading and trailing whitespace is trimmed in the cast automatically.

If there are already some rows in the table, existing values are cast back and forth, too, which triggers a whole table rewrite and bloats the table. **Not efficient for big tables.**

4. If you cannot easily fix your CSV and cannot afford to tinker with the target table (or just don't want to bloat it), use a **temporary staging table** as `COPY` target, then `INSERT` from there:

```sql
CREATE TEMP tmp_invtest5 AS TABLE invtest5 LIMIT 0;  -- copy basic structure

ALTER TABLE tmp_invtest5
  ALTER unit_cost TYPE text
, ALTER total     TYPE text;     -- both columns?

COPY TO tmp_invtest5 ...

INSERT INTO invtest5 
      (orderdate, region, rep, item, units, unit_cost, total)
SELECT orderdate, region, rep, item, units, replace(unit_cost, ',', '')::numeric
                                          , replace(total    , ',', '')::numeric
FROM   tmp_invtest5
-- ORDER BY ??? -- while being at it?
```

The temporary table is dropped automatically at the end of the session. If you need it gone before that, `DROP TABLE tmp_invtest5;`.

Related:

- [How to update selected rows with values from a CSV file in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910494/how-to-update-selected-rows-with-values-from-a-csv-file-in-postgres/8910810#8910810)
- [How to ignore errors with psql \copy meta-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36634360/how-to-ignore-errors-with-psql-copy-meta-command/36635312#36635312)

Comment: Thank you for the help! I ended up just altering the type of the columns. Just when I started to think I knew SQL this hit me haha. I appreciate the help!